# Installing Python Modules through Website

Tags: php, python, pip, cpanel

I recently have a website running a python script. Unfortunately, this python script requires another python module but I do not know how to install it on the website. How do you install a python module for a website. Below is my code

PHP:

```
<?php

$VAR = 'test';
$output = shell_exec('python test.py ' . $VAR);
//$output = shell_exec('python -m pip install requests'); <-- tried that but does not work.

echo $output;
?>
```

Python Code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('google.com')
print (response.text)
```

I do not get anything when I go to my php page, but if I hastag import requests and response and print and just put "print ("Hi")" it works. Any ideas on how to install requests?

Is there anyway I can get a shell for a website?

NOTE: I AM USING CPANEL.

Comment: You've tagged this with `pip` so presumably you tried `pip install requests`?

Comment: I tried that on php. I did shell_exec('pip install requests');, but I don't think it works. I know pip install requests works on a computer, but this is a website. How do I access the shell if I can?

Comment: _why_ would you need to do this on a website? Do you not own the server it's running from? If you do, _why_ would you want to be able to execute this kind of command from a website?

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions at all.

Comment: The point is, I need to run `pip install requests` to install the requests module to run the script. But, I cannot do that because there is not a shell for a website

Comment: Lets start small.  Does running your Python Script by itself function as designed?

Comment: If this PHP script is hosted on some shared hosting environment (as implied by your usage of cPanel) what you want to achieve is not going to work.  Please upgrade your hosting environment to one that includes a proper shell (such as a VPS).

Comment: Running the python script does function.

Comment: Yeah, this is not going to end well. `requests` depends on `cryptography` and you're not going to be able to install that without a compiler. (Or an operating system install package.)

Comment: So by that, I have no way of doing it?

Comment: Not with a CPanel based host. That kind of hosting doesn't really work for Python.